# Rails - combine field name with prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my user model (`Rails 3`, `devise`, `mongoid`) I have some fields starting with a prefix:

```
class User
 ...

 field :usr_feature1, type: Boolean
 field :usr_feature2, type: Boolean
 field :usr_feature3, type: Boolean
 field :usr_feature4, type: Boolean

 ...
end
```

I need a function which allows for checking those fields for `true`/`false` like so:

```
def check_usr "feature_id"
  # return true if e.g. usr_feature1 is true
end
```

How can I "combine" a prefix with the field name passed into this function? The only solution I could come up with was to create a "check function" for every field which is cumbersome and I suspect there is an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't know about Mongoid, but with Boolean columns Rails usually generates methods with an extra `?`: `User.first.usr_feature1?` should exist and return true/false

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that - and it seems to work with `mongoid`, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do, assuming `feature_id` is a number

```
def check_usr(feature_id)
  !!self["usr_feature#{feature_id}"]
end
```

Comment: This could return nil, but he wants only true/false

Comment: Added `!!` to take care of that

Comment: Thank you, this will do just fine, but what if `feature_id` would be a string (e.g. the field is named `usr_feature_something`)? Will a simple `to_s` do the trick?

Comment: It will work just fine, you dont need to call `to_s` on a String